# How set query SQL COUNT - distinct but value is unique

Tags: sql, unique, distinct

How to write the correct query to SQL language by example?

Before asking SQL:

```
|     User       |    City    |
|----------------|------------|
| John Travolta  | New York   |
| Anonymous      | New Jersey |
| John Travolta  | New York   |
| Anonymous      | New Jersey |
| John Travolta  | New York   |
| Bill Gates     | New Haven  |
```

After asking SQL will return:

Total Records:

```
New York - 1
New Jersey - 2
New Haven - 1
```

Note:

DISTINCT - more values John Travolta will count only 1
DISTINCT - one value Anonymous will count 1
DISTINCT - three values Anonymous will count 3
DISTINCT - five values John Travolta will count only 1

---

Please look to [ttps://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_no_distinct](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_no_distinct)

Then:

```
SELECT country, count(DISTINCT city) as total_records FROM Customers WHERE country="Spain" GROUP BY country
```

I want after asking SQL:

Country total_records
Spain   5

Because Value in column only Madrid is as unique.

Comment: You want to use SQL to query HTML? I think that's possible, but not really what SQL is for.

Comment: No HTML. Only SQL.

Comment: I think you are going to confuse people with that HTML table. I assume it's included to show us an example of your data?

Comment: Then what is that HTML in your question for?

Comment: For example: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_no_distinct                                                                                          SELECT * FROM [Customers] WHERE Country = "Spain";                                                 then I want after SQL asking :                                                                         
Spain = 1 country, City = 5 because: Madrid is as value unique. If two values Sevilla - will only count 1, if two values Barcelona - count will only 1, but if five values Madrid then count will 5.

Comment: Can you show us your database scheme?

Comment: mypetlion:  You can to look scheme database: 

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_no_distinct
Then SQL query:

SELECT country, count(DISTINCT city) as total_records FROM [Customers] WHERE country = "Spain" group by country;

I want:

I want after SQL asking : Spain = 1 country, City = 5 because: Madrid is as value unique. If two values Sevilla - will only count 1, if two values Barcelona - count will only 1, but if five values Madrid then count will 5

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT City, COUNT(DISTINCT User2)
FROM 
    (SELECT City, User
    , CASE WHEN User= 'Anonymous' THEN CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY City) AS VARCHAR(10)) ELSE User END AS User2 
    FROM MyTable) a --Replace MyTable with the name of your table
GROUP BY City
```

It assigns a unique numeric value to each "Anonymous" entry, then counts the distinct number of those, or of non-Anonymous names.

Comment: I ask you: Why FROM #temp ) a - ???? Word: a ???? FROM table_name) a ???

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - you would replace #temp with whatever the name of your table is.  I have edited to make that clearer.

Comment: APH: I understand, but why word:       a           ????   FROM MyTable)     a ????

Comment: It's an alias.  You have to assign an alias to a subquery in order to use it as your source.  Try running without it and see what happens.

Comment: `<?php require 'database/db.php';
        $pdo = DB::connect();
        $pdo -> exec("set names utf8");  
      SELECT City, COUNT(DISTINCT User2) as total_records FROM (SELECT City, User, CASE WHEN User= 'Anonymous' THEN CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY City) AS VARCHAR(10)) ELSE User END AS User2 
    FROM MyTable) a GROUP BY City
        

echo "<table>";
 foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
echo "<tr ><td>$row[City]</td><td>$row[total_records]</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>"; ?>`


This does not working :(

Comment: Please post as a new question with the entire code - my answer is specific to sql server, since you specified your question was only about the SQL intially.  If you are using other dbms, please make sure to add all relevant tags.  I can't help you with php.

Comment: Yes, all implementing part is yours because you asked only for `SQL` issue so you will get `SQL` solution only.